# ¿Cómo guardar datos de un ciclo en distintas variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy en mi primera semana aprendiendo python, estoy haciendo un programa y lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

```
#el programa pide al usuario cuantas veces pedir ciertos datos
print("Cuantos alumnos hay en la clase: ")
num = input()
#de acuerdo a ese número, serán las veces que se pidan datos como nombre, edad, etc.
veces = 1
while veces <= num:
#(pide los datos)
veces += 1
```

aqui mi problema es que quiero mostrar los datos hasta el final del programa, como por ejemplo:

```
print("Los datos de los ", num, " son: ", XXX)
```

si quiero que se impriman cada que pasa una iteración del while no tengo problema pues se van guardando los datos en la variable que quiera y los mando a imprimir, pero cuando los quiero imprimir TODOS AL FINAL, ya no sé como hacerle ya que la variable se sobrescribe, en otros lenguajes (y sé que hago mal quizás al querer pensar en como se hace en otros) solo basta con hacer un `for` y también hago una variable que vaya aumentando y listo, cada que pasa una iteración se escribe en la primera variable y voy aumentando esa variable, pero aquí en python no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo, lo que logre hasta ahora es crear una lista y a esa lista ir agregándole el contenido de la siguiente iteración con `append()`, cuando lo muestro me sale toda la lista: `[('marcos', '26', ['py']), ('carlos', '22', ['java']), ('karla', '29', ['c++'])]` y no con el orden que quisiera, por ejemplo:

```
<<los datos de los X alumnos son:
<<alumno 1:
<<Nombre: XXXX, Edad: XXX, Curso: XXXX
<<alumnos 2:
<<Nombre: XXXX, Edad: XXX, Curso: XXXX
```

y así sucesivamente, me pueden decir como hacerle?

mi problema radica desde como guardar los datos de cada alumno en una variable distinta cada vez que se ejecuta el `while`.

mi programa es este:

```
class alumno:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, cursos):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.cursos = [cursos]   //esta asi porque despues quiero que pueda añadir mas cursos
    def mas_cursos(self, curso):   /*todo esto es para hacer otras cosas despues, ignorenlo
        self.cursos.append(curso)   
    def menos_cursos(self, curso):
        self.cursos.remove(curso)                       hasta aqui*/

print("Ingrese el número de alumnos inscritos en la academia: ")
num1 = int(input(">"))
num = 1
lista = []

while num <= num1:
    print("Alumno ", num)
    print("Nombre:")
    nom = input()
    print("Edad:")
    ed = input()
    print("Curso:")
    cur = input()
    alumno1 = alumno(nom, ed, cur)
    final = alumno1.nombre, alumno1.edad, alumno1.cursos
    lista.append(final)
    print("\n")
    num += 1

print("Los datos de los ", num-1, " alumnos son:\n", lista)
```

Comment: para que la lista no te salga en ese formato puedes usar `''.join(lista)`

Answer (score 1):

Creo oportuno agregar otra respuesta con consejos sobre como puedes mejorar tu código y una solución alternativa que permite manipular fácilmente la visualización de los datos con el método `__str__` de la clase.

Mejoras del código recomendables:

1. Es innecesario crear un `print()` con una explicación para el `input()` cuando puedes hacer `input("Agregue su nombre aquí >")` y ahorrarte varias líneas de código.
2. También puedes ahorrarte un poco de código si en el momento de la creación del objeto de la clase `Alumnos` das valor a sus atributos directamente con los `inputs()`. *(Esto probablemente sea más claro viendo mi ejemplo)*
3. Ya que cuentas con una clase puedes crear un método que devuelva los datos de la misma de forma legible en una string, lo cual sería más pythonico.
4. En tu programa faltaba la lógica necesaria para obtener los elementos de la lista cursos, esto lo implementas manipulando strings como `curso1, curso2` con las funciones: `replace(' ','')` que eliminará los espacios en blanco y split(',') que separará la string en cada una de sus comas creando así los elementos de la lista.
5. En Python no se comenta el código con `//` o `/* */` que es lo típico en JavaScript. Más bien, puedes comentar una línea con `#`, varias con `"""   """` y también contamos con `# ToDo: tarea por hacer` que es un comentario que recibe un color diferente en los IDE, el cual se utiliza para indicar las cosas que faltan por implementar.
6. En Python casi nunca será necesario usar un `print()` vacío para hacer un salto de línea, más bien añade `\n` al inicio o final del `print()` de esta manera `print("\nTexto\n")`.
7. Nunca pongas acentos o eñes al interno de tu código ni siquiera en comentarios, para evitar errores.
8. Generalmente es una buena práctica poner los nombres de las clases con la primera letra en mayúscula, aunque en Python no sea obligatorio ayuda a una mejor comprensión y lectura del código.
9. En **edad** al igual que hiciste con el **número de alumnos** podemos hacer una validación para recibir solo números enteros.

Todos estos consejos aplicados a tu código ya revisado te los dejo aquí:

```
class Alumno:
    def __init__(self, nombre, edad, cursos):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.edad = edad
        self.cursos = list(cursos.replace(' ','').split(',')) # Una lista para varios cursos.

    def __str__(self):
        """ Devuelve los datos en formato legible """
        return f"Nombre: {self.nombre}, Edad: {self.edad}, Cursos: {', '.join(self.cursos)}"

    # ToDo: Hacer otras cosas luego.
    """
    def mas_cursos(self, curso):
        self.cursos.append(curso)   
    def menos_cursos(self, curso):
        self.cursos.remove(curso)
    """

lista = []
num1 = int(input("\nIngrese el número de alumnos inscritos en la academia: "))

num = 1
while num <= num1:
    print("\nAlumno:", num)

    objeto = Alumno(
    nombre = input("Nombre: "),
    edad = int(input("Edad: ")),
    cursos = input("Curso: ")
    )

    lista.append(objeto)
    num += 1

print("\nLos datos de los", num-1, "alumnos son:")
[print(f"Alumno: {i+1}\n" + l.__str__()) for i, l in enumerate(lista)]
```

> Uso `f"..{i+1}"` porque es más elegante, pero si usas una versión inferior a Python 3 tendrás que cambiarlo por lo siguiente: `"Alumno: ", i+1, "\n"` y también en el return del método `__str__`.

Devuelve:

```
Los datos de los 2 alumnos son:
Alumno: 1
Nombre: Luis Pérez, Edad: 26, Cursos: Ciencias, Leyes
Alumno: 2
Nombre: Ramón Días, Edad: 27, Cursos: Física, Química
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema lo tienes en que si quieres imprimir todos los datos al acabar el programa, no puedes hacer el uso siguiente:

```
print("Los datos de los ", num-1, " alumnos son:\n", lista)
```

Para que te recoga todos los datos guardados, ya tienes la variable lista que es una lista. Lo que debes hacer es recorrerla.
Otra cosa, para iterar en bucle for un objeto, no hace falta aumentar ninguna variable si no quieres hacer uso de ella.

#### Prueba con esto:

```
[print("Los datos de los ", num-1, " alumnos son:\n", l) for l in lista]
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
Los datos de los  2  alumnos son:
 ('Luis', '21', ['3'])
Los datos de los  2  alumnos son:
 ('Marcos', '22', ['4'])
```

Si por el contrario quieres que te salga como aquí:

```
<<los datos de los X alumnos son:
<<alumno 1:
<<Nombre: XXXX, Edad: XXX, Curso: XXXX
<<alumnos 2:
<<Nombre: XXXX, Edad: XXX, Curso: XXXX
```

Prueba a hacer el for con enumerate:

```
# Cambia esto:
print("Los datos de los ", num-1, " alumnos son:\n", lista)
# Por esto:
print("Los datos de los " + str(len(lista)) + " alumnos son:")
[print("alumno " + str(index + 1) + ":\n" + "nombre:" + str(l[0]) + ", Edad: " + str(l[1]) + ", Curso: " + str(l[2])) for index, l in enumerate(lista)]
```

La salida es la siguiente:
(El curso aparece como array, porque está así guardado.)

```
Los datos de los 2 alumnos son:
alumno 1:
nombre:Marcos, Edad: 21, Curso: ['4']
alumno 2:
nombre:Luis, Edad: 24, Curso: ['5']
```

PD: Cuando comentes, no hagas como java o js ya que los comentarios se hacen con #
Varias cosas que cambiaría, yo guardaría los objetos en una lista de diccionarios, no en una lista de tuplas. Así puedes acceder con la key necesarias más fácilmente y no tener que mapear.
Otro punto, comprueba en el input qué tipo de datos son, ya que puedes meter en el curso o en la edad un string. Ánimo y a seguir aprendiendo!